# Populating a UIPIckerView with remote JSON array

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am downloading a JSON Array from a remote server:

```
var colores = [Colores]()


func downloadJSONColores(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
         let url = URL(string: "https://../colores.php")


         URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data,response,error) in

            print(data as Any)
            print(response as Any)

         if error == nil {
             do {
                 self.colores = try JSONDecoder().decode([Colores].self, from: data!)

                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     completed()
                 }

             }catch{

             }

         }
         }.resume()


     }
```

I have a struct class for Colores:

```
struct Colores:Decodable {

    let id: Int
    let nombre: String
    let icono: String
    let modelo: Int
    let caracterista: Int

}
```

What I need is to populate a PickerView with the decoded JSON objects, showing the field nombre as title and storing the field id from the pickerview selected item.

I am calling the downloadJSONColores method in viewDidLoad as follows:

```
downloadJSONColores {
            coloresPV.reloadData()
                     }
```

where coloresPV is my pickerView, but obviously this way of doing this only works for collectionViews, not for pickerViews.
 Which would be the best way to populate the pickerView while executing downloadJSONColores?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem decoding the JSON Array directly at viewDidLoad method as follows:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://..")!
let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
    if let error = error { print(error); return }
    do {
        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Colores].self, from: data!)
        print(result)
        self.colores = result.map{$0.self}
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.coloresPV.reloadAllComponents()
        }
    } catch { print(error) }
}
dataTask.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [UIPickerViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdatasource) and [UIPickerViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate) protocols.

If I understand your question correctly, you'll need to keep a variable `colors: [Colores]` in your ViewController.

Then:

- Return `colors.count` in your implementation of the `func numberOfComponents(in: UIPickerView) -> Int` function of `UIPickerViewDataSource`,
- Return the correct title in your implementation in the method `pickerView(UIPickerView, titleForRow: Int, forComponent: Int) -> String?` function of `UIPickerViewDelegate`